# In Python, the pyqt QWebEngineView win32gui EnumWindows program crashes

Tags: python-3.x, win32gui, qwebengineview

In Python, I used these two:

```
pyqt QWebEngineView 
win32gui EnumWindows
```

and I only called `EnumWindows` after the `QWebEngineView` was loaded and it crashed, But there are no errors when I run two grammars independently?

What could be causing it to crash?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the code you are using that crashes. Also explain or show how it crashes, is there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

When I use QwebEngine EnumWindows GetWindowText method will have several window directly under an error, I didn't find the reason, because we only need a few window, so under the EnumWindows GetClassName method of judgment, value I need for a title.This bug has no error message, it just crashes.